# Python - Printing A Specific Part Of A Config Line

Tags: python, network-programming

I'm having trouble copying information from a config file for switches I work with. When I run the below script it gives me a full line of, 'Switchport Access Vlan 99' for example. The problem is that I just want/need it to return 'Vlan 99'. Any suggestions?

```
input_file = open('X:\\abc\\def\\ghi.txt', 'r')
output_file = open('X:\\abc\\def\\jkl.txt', 'w')
for line in input_file:
    if "vlan" in line:
        print(line)
        output_file.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that all the lines starts with  'Switchport Access' you can just use the string method `replace`

```
line = "Switchport Access Vlan 99"
interesting_part = line.replace("Switchport Access ", "")
```

Comment: Thank you, I can adapt that to use for a few different things that are a similar in the config files that I'm working with. Kept seeing advice saying to try and use a string.split or .rsplit for it.

Comment: Glad to help, please accept my answer if it was useful to you and welcome to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the contents of the files you may have to do something different.

If each like is "Some random text Vlan 99" then you could use:

```
for line in input_file:
  if "vlan" in line:
    s = line[line.find("Vlan"):]
    print(s)
    output_file.write(s)
```

`line.find("text")` return the index of the string if found, -1 otherwise.
`line[N:]` returns the substring from an index to the end.

For another way of getting the substring out you could look into `line.split()` and then take the last element of that list to get your number.